# Powershell parse CSV and delete row

Tags: parsing, powershell, csv

I have a CSV file with three columns. I need to parse the csv file and delete a row if column1 does not match having 5 numeric characters. So if the example below, I want to delete rows 1,2 and keep rows 3,4.

```
Column1,Column2,Column3
user1,22,547
user2,55,321
54321,3,223
12345,99,125
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? If not, have a look at `help Import-CSV -full` and `help Export-CSV -full`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use select-object with a regular expression :

```
Import-Csv 'C:\temp\col.csv' | where {$_.column1 -match '[\d]{5}'} | Export-Csv 'C:\temp\colMod.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: I forgot I changed the name of my columns, but yes it works. Thanks.